# How to quickly identify which type of plot I should use?

Tags: r, plot

We have a lot of types of plots available in R. And every single time I get a dataset, I have to think for a long time that which type of plot I should use to plot my dataset in order to get information I want (I'm a beginner of R). I don't know whether it's related to my math and stats knowledge or just not familiar with R tech skills. Anybody can tell me the reasons and how to improve that? Thanks many in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.r-bloggers.com/7-visualizations-you-should-learn-in-r/

Comment: I'm so glad the pie chart was not in the top 7 there. For your question, you're usually not far from the correct plot if you use the `plot` function because it's so generic.

Comment: @Edward I am surprised pie chart is mentioned at all (only in the picture tho). Simplest rule is never use pie chars. Also, personally I do think you should not use boxplots, they are super informative while implying to be the opposite. Rather go for RDI plots (yarrr!).

Comment: @Edward but I think plot function can just do little thing.

Comment: @Annet hhh I'm a beginner even don't know what is RDI plots. Thanks for giving me a new window!!!

Comment: @Chris check out [the pirateplot package (yarrr!)](https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/pirateplot.html), it is fantastic. When you know about these you never even want a boxplot anymore.

Comment: @Annet hhh OK!!!

Comment: Take a look [here](https://datavizcatalogue.com/search.html) to know what type of plot to use. Then, see [this book](https://rkabacoff.github.io/datavis/index.html) to know how to make plots with R and finally [this one](https://serialmentor.com/dataviz/index.html) to improve your plots and make them understandable

Comment: @bretauv Wow your suggestion is so logic and helpful. I will do that! Thank you so much!